# iOS, getting a 'snapshot' of available Bonjour services

Tags: ios, bonjour, nsnetservice, nsnetservicebrowser

For my iOS app I want to check when starting if there is a specific service advertised using Bonjour and if so connect to that host (instead of a specified URL).

I have implemented in my code:

```
if (self.services) {
    [self.services removeAllObjects];
} else {
    self.services = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    self.serviceBrowser = [[NSNetServiceBrowser alloc] init];

    [self.serviceBrowser setDelegate:self];
    [self.serviceBrowser searchForServicesOfType:@"_myapp1._tcp." inDomain:@""];
}
```

If a service is found, `didFindService` is called and through a NSNotificationCenter I get the result service hostname and port and proceed as usual.

If a service is NOT found, my app stays there... waiting... (I know it is as expected).

Is there a way to say that after e.g. 5sec 'abort'? Somehow I need to call the `[self.serviceBrowser stop]` but I don't see such option. How should I be able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to roll your own timeout using something like NSTimer.